# Having trouble accessing Documents using the cd command on Git Bash

Tags: command, git-bash, file-handling, cd

I'm trying to access the Documents folder, I succeeded in doing so but there's some weird error which isn't letting me see my files and changing the contents of the folder OR it's accessing a different folder.

**Documents folder:**

[image]

**Command:**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you're giving us enough information to answer this one, with these partial screen captures. But, in Git Bash, after doing `cd ~/Documents`, does `pwd -P` show you the folder you expect? It will tell you where Git Bash thinks that folder is and could explain the difference. I've had `~` end up on a network drive at some point, instead of my C drive, for example.

Comment: I used the pwd -P just now, it turns out it's accessing the Documents folder in the current user's folder. How do I access the default Documents folder? (You know, the one with on the left under Quick Access

Comment: Hum, under Quick Access, the folder I get *is* the current user's Documents folder.

Comment: Did you reconfigure Quick Access by any chance, to show something different? If it's some kind of meta folder combining stuff from multiple sources, like Windows does sometimes, Git Bash probably cannot see it. It can see real folders that exist on your actual hard drive.

Comment: Is one of those folders maybe linked to OneDrive? See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-file-explorer-quick-access-vs-this-pc/b284cf1a-d5b4-45ca-b3fc-28e2d8efe359

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure I linked those folders to One Drive.

Comment: Wait so like, is there something different that I have to do if it's linked to OneDrive?

Comment: Update: I looked at that article and turns out, since it's linked to my OneDrive, it changed it's path. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, since I had my Documents linked with OneDrive, it changed it's location path.